# Bizzare problem with output file from write.csv function in R. The csv output file needs to be opened and closed before working as expected

Tags: r, csv

This is an incredibly strange and possibly specific problem, but I can't think of where else to turn. I have a script in R that generates a dataframe which I then export to a csv file, I then take that CSV file and feed it into third party software.

The file is generated normally (or so it seems) but when I feed it into the third party software, the data does not get transmitted properly. Specifically, data that is formatted as dates seems to get lost. By this I mean the data is read by the third party software a "NA", even though it is very clearly there.

However, if I open the csv file in excel, save it and close out of it (changing absolutely nothing else), the file works properly. The dates come in as expected

I was wondering if anyone could lend some guidance on whether there's something going on when R generates a csv file that would cause it to behave differently in this way.

Why would opening, saving and closing the file seemingly fix it? I know it's a longshot, just wondering if there was something in the way that R generates a csv that would cause strange behavior.

Is it possible that excel is somehow modifying the CSV as I save it in a way that's not obvious and that somehow makes the file function properly? I don't know enough about computers or software generally to know these sorts of things.

Comment: Can you please clarify what specifically you mean by "data that is formatted as dates seems to get lost"?

Comment: @JonSpring Hey sure, sorry about that. The dates get read as "NA", yet for some strange reason opening, saving, and closing the file fixes the problem. It's so strange. I don't even know where to begin or how to even google it, the third party software people are impossible to get a hold of.

Comment: Compare the files!!  FileFromR  vs  FileFromExcel.

Comment: @donPablo the files appear identical when I open them to view them, I've looked at them in notepad, in excel and they appear identical. I'm thinking the issue is something deeper (I have no idea what) in the way the files are stored somehow. When you open them they are identical

Comment: I use WinMerge to compare files, which highlights any row differences, and character differences, or any extra/missing characters in either file.  Eyeball.EXE just does not work as well.

Comment: I'll try that out, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Excel has a very long history of mangling CSV files by aggressively converting strings to numbers or dates when it feels like it. The most likely thing is absolutely that your 3rd party software is less flexible on input date formats than Excel is, but that it does understand whatever Excel has modified your original data with.

Comment: What is the filetype that is saved out of Excel?  Is it still CSV? 
 or has it become XLS (or some variation of XL....)?  If it has been converted to an XLS, then some Excel logic has been applied. 
And each column now has a explicit data type that was not part of the CSV.
Can you attach the first 10 rows of each file and share them with us?

Comment: @donPablo The "Excel logic" is applied when you *open* the file, so the file type of the final result is irrelevant, it still applies to .csv. Put the string "2019-09-07" in a text file with a .csv extension, open in Excel, then save it, still as .csv. With my version of Excel and in my locale, the file now contains the string "9/7/2019".

Comment: @ChrisHaug THANK YOU SO MUCH! Your insight that the excel logic is applied when the file is opened and what you said afterwards is exactly what I needed! The file was coming out on a mm-dd-yyyy format when it needed to be in mm/dd/yyyy format, it appears excel was doing that automatically on open so I could never tell the difference between the original file and the file after I opened and saved it in excel. But your insight led to the fix. Thank you so so so so very much.